# How to find the mean and standard deviation having different variable in same column

Tags: pandas

Data frame

```
id  insert  dollars
0   148 Standard    2232.771979
1   572 New Promotion   1403.807542
2   973 Standard    2327.092181
3   1096    Standard    1280.030541
4   1541    New Promotion   1513.563200
```

- Find the mean of insert which is `Standard` and `New Promotion`
- Find the standard deviation of insert which is `Standard` and`New Promotion`

pseudo code

```
mean1 = df.groupby['Standard'].agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
mean2 = df.groupby['New Promotion'].agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))

Stdv1 = df.groupby['Standard'].agg(lambda x: np.std(x))
Stdv2 = df.groupby['New Promotion'].agg(lambda x: np.std(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for someting like this?

with pandas 0.25+

```
df.groupby('insert').agg(mean=('dollars', 'mean'),std=('dollars', 'std')).reset_index()
```

with pandas below 0.25+

```
df.groupby('insert')['dollars'].agg([('mean', 'mean'), ('std', 'std')]).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
           insert   mean            std
0   New Promotion   1458.685371     77.608970
1   Standard        1946.631567     579.216515
```

Comment: TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: I tried on the DF you provided & it is working fine. Named aggregation needs pandas 0.25+

Comment: `df1.groupby('insert').agg({'dollars': [('dollars_sd','std'), ('dollars_mean','mean')]})` this one is working fine but not like your output

Comment: If you are using a older version of pandas, please use the updated code.